# RestfulRouting for .Net Changing default 'id' param

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

Pretty basic question but I cant seem to find it in the documentation. I've been integrating [RestfulRouting](http://restfulrouting.com) (via nuget) into an Mvc 4 app but there are situations where it would be nice to tweak the the params, either change the name or have more than one argument into the controller action.

e.g.

```
/resource/:id/:slug

public ActionResult Show(int id, string slug) { return View(); }
```

or

```
/resource/:custom_param_name

public ActionResult Show(string custom_param_name) { return View(); }
```

Is there an example or documentation that covers this scenario?

Comment: I read through some of the documentation and http://restfulrouting.com/mappings/resources#naming might give hints on how to choose a different naming but seeing how the framework you chose merges routes together I believe it might not be possible to have multiple parameters... Sadly don't have the time right now to do a deep dive in to the code of the RestfulRouting to figure it out.

Comment: Have you tried out AttributeRouting? attributerouting.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand right you are trying to [Route by name, not by id.](http://danpesolutions.blogspot.co.il/2012/10/route-by-name-not-by-id.html) with RestfulRouting.

I'm no sure if it's 100% possible, but you can try **Create Custom Routes**:

*Two additional methods are provided so you can add custom routes to the route set if you need to. Map is a chainable method that allows you to add standard mappings. Route is a method that will allow you to add a custom route to the route set.*

### e.g.

```
Map("posts/{year}/{slug}")
  .To<PostsController>(x => x.Post(-1, ""))
  .Constrain("slug", @"\w+")
  .Constrain("year", @"\d+");
Route(new Route("posts/{action}", 
  new RouteValueDictionary(new { controller = "posts" }), 
  new MvcRouteHandler());
```

---

### or

```
Map("resource/{custom_param}")
  .To<ResourcesController>(x => x.Resource(-1, ""))
  .Constrain("custom_param", @"\w+");
Route(new Route("resource/custom", 
  new RouteValueDictionary(new { controller = "resource" }), 
  new MvcRouteHandler());
```

So you can use:

```
public ActionResult Custom(string custom_param) { return View(); }
```

### How to use it ?

```
public class Routes : RouteSet
{
    public override void Map(Mapper map)
    {
        map.Root<HomeController>(x => x.Show());
        map.Path("test/{id}").To<TestController>(x => x.Test()).Constrain("id", @"\d+");
        map.Resource<SessionsController>();
        map.Resources<BlogsController>(blogs =>
        {
            blogs.As("weblogs");
            blogs.Only("index", "show");
            blogs.Collection(x => {
                x.Get("latest");
                x.Post("someaction");
            );
            blogs.Member(x => x.Put("move"));

            blogs.Resources<PostsController>(posts =>
            {
                posts.Except("create", "update", "destroy");
                posts.Resources<CommentsController>(c => c.Except("destroy"));
            });
        });
    }
}

public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        ViewEngines.Engines.Clear();
        ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new RestfulRoutingViewEngine());

        RouteTable.Routes.MapRoutes<Routes>();
    }
}
```

*How to use: [Restful Routing for ASP .NET MVC](https://github.com/stevehodgkiss/restful-routing)*

*Full guide for this can be found here: [RestfulRouting](http://stevehodgkiss.github.com/restful-routing/)*

Comment: can you clarify where the `Map(string url)` method is used in context of? In my routeset class, I override `Map(Imapper map)` and currently have all the mapped resources in there

Comment: I really didn't have the chance to do it using RestfulRouting library. but i know it from Rails, so it should be similier.
I added a better code example with the override you were talking about.